# Search a table for a specific field and also count in the results

Tags: sql

I have a table like this, called JOBNAME

| Job | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Engineer | Alex |
| Engineer | Frank |
| SDE | John |
| SDE | Frank |
| SDE | Mason |

I'm trying to get the following output

| Job | Name | Job Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engineer | Alex | 2 |
| Engineer | Frank | 2 |
| SDE | John | 3 |
| SDE | Frank | 3 |
| SDE | Mason | 3 |

Here is my query:

```
select job, name, count(job) as 'Job Count'
from JOBNAME
group by count(job)
```

I keeping getting errors on different version of this sql code.

Comment: What queries have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I can't understand the expected result. Do you mean you want the number of people having the same Job as Frank?

Comment: Have columns, not  aggregate functions in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for identifiers, e.g. "Job Count".

Comment: @Orion447 - The query I tried in listed in the descrption.  I get "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression" Error

Comment: @jarlh - Count of all engineers in the output column called "Job count" and then count of all SDE in the output column called "job Count" for all results that have Frank.

Comment: @apadia That's still not clear.

Comment: I edited my problem and removed the where statement which was making it confusion.  Sorry for the churn, it is my first time posting and I now realize the level of detail I need to provide.  In the future I will post something more similar to the exact problem I am trying to solve vs a scaled down version.

Comment: Your question as it is now has nothing to do with the original question. If you have a new requirement you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information yet to fully answer the question, because there are contradictions between the data and question text.

This will give the results you asked for based on the data, but it's probably still wrong:

```
select job, min(name) as Name, count(job) as 'Job Count'
from JOBNAME
group by job
```

The problem is if you legitimately limit the results to `Frank`'s jobs, the counts are wrong. That is, this query, which is probably actually correct:

```
select job, name, count(job) as 'Job Count'
from JOBNAME
where name= 'Frank'
group by job, name
```

Will produce this output:

| Job | Name | Job Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engineer | Frank | 1 |
| SDE | Frank | 1 |

Because Frank only completed ONE of each kind of job.

If you really want the results shown in the question, the `WHERE name='Frank'` part of the query serves no purpose relative to the sample data and there's not enough information to know the basic for limiting the data or name.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20);
SET @name = 'Frank'

select job, @name, count(job) as 'Job Count'
from JOBNAME
where JOB IN (SELECT JOB FROM JOBNAME WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = @name)
group by job, @name
```

if you only want one name

If you want this summary for each name and job,

```
SELECT eachCombo.Job, Name, JobQty 'Job Count'
(SELECT Job, Name FROM JOBNAME) eachCombo INNER JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(Job) JobQty, Job FROM JOBNAME GROUP BY Job) eachSum ON eachCombo.Job = eachSum.Job
```